# Scikit - Format Output of Polynomial Regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, non-linear-regression

I doing polynomial regression with scikit learn and try to interpret the coefficients. But somehow scikit doesn't format the output. So it looks like this:

```
[ 0.,0.95545289,0.,0.20682341,-0.,0.,-0.,-0.,0.,0.,0.,-0.,0.,-0.,-0.,]
```

How can I map the coefficients to the features which where created? 
Code I have so far:

```
poly = PolynomialFeatures(interaction_only=True)
X_ = poly.fit_transform(X_train_minmax)
X_test1 = poly.fit_transform(X_test_minmax)

lasso_model = linear_model.LassoCV(cv = 10, copy_X = True, normalize = False)
lasso_fit = lasso_model.fit(X_, y_train)
lasso_path = lasso_model.score(X_, y_train)
y_pred= lasso_model.predict(X_test1)
lasso_model.coef_
```

Thx!

Comment: Did you try `zip(X_.columns, lasso_model.coef_)`?

Comment: Hey, thanks for ur reply. unfortunately X_ isnt a DataFrame but a matrix in array representation.  So .columns isnt working here

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html) in `PolynomialFeatures`:

> `powers_[i, j]` is the exponent of the jth input in the ith output.

So something like this should work:

```
columns = ['_'.join(['x{var}^{exp}'.format(var=var, exp=exp) for var, exp in enumerate(a[i, :])]) for i in range(a.shape[0])
zip(columns, lasso_model.coef_)
```

The important line is the first one. :)

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume you are running a 2nd degree polynomial regression. So,

```
poly = PolynomialFeature(degree =2)  #generate a polynomial object
X_ = poly.fit_transform(input_data)  #ndarray to be used for regression.
```

where `input_data = [X1,X2,X3,...] #actually ndarray represented as a List for simplicity`

To find the index in the list `Lasso.coef_` where (say) X1 factors are present,i.e, X1, X1**2, X1*X2, X1*X3,...X1*Xn, use the following

```
list_of_index = []
```

`for j in range(len(input_data)):#iterate over each input, X1, X2, etc
     temp =[]
     for i in X_.shape[1]:#iterate over the polynomial ndarray object columnwise
         if poly.powers_[i,j] != 0:
            temp.append(i)
     list_of_index.append(temp)`

list_of_index will be a list of lists containing index of the positions which have factors of X1, X2, etc..

Example:

For a 2nd degree regression using only X1 and X2,
the generated ndarray will be `[1 , X1, X2, X1**2, X1*X2, X2**2]`

list_of_lists would be [[1,3,4],[2,4,5]]

You could use this to access `lasso_model.coef_`